# How to efficiently extract data from one dataframe to another in R?

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I have two dataframes. One that consists of a vector of integers, for example:

```
set.seed(10)

# create
dt1 <- data.table(INT = sample(1:110000, 10000, replace = F))

# sort
dt1 <- dt1[order(INT),]
```

One that details categories for different integers. For example:

```
# create
dt2 <- data.table(CAT = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 1000, replace = T),
              INT_START = sample(1:100000, 1000, replace = F),
              INT_END = sample(1:100000, 1000, replace = F))

# ensure start <= end 
tmp1 <- subset(dt2, dt2$INT_END < dt2$INT_START)
colnames(tmp1) <- c("CAT", "INT_END", "INT_START")
tmp2 <- subset(dt2, dt2$INT_END >= dt2$INT_START)
dt2 <- rbind(tmp1, tmp2)
rm(tmp1, tmp2)

# sort
dt2 <- dt2[order(CAT, INT_START),]
```

I need to identify the categories associated with each integer. I can do this using a for loop, for example:

```
dt1$CAT <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(dt1)){
  ann.ind <- which(dt2$INT_START <= dt1$INT[i] & dt2$INT_END >= dt1$INT[i])
  dt1$CAT[i] <- paste0(unique(dt2$CAT[ann.ind]), collapse = "")
  print(i)
}
```

However, I need to apply this to multiple very large datasets, and this is far too slow. I can get partway there with data.table, by doing:

```
test1 <- dt2[dt1, on=.(INT_START<=INT, INT_END>=INT), allow.cartesian = T]
```

And then formatting the result:

```
if (identical(test1$INT_END, test1$INT_START)){
  test1 <- test1[,c("INT_END", "CAT")]
  colnames(test1) <- c("INT", "CAT")
  test1 <- test1[!duplicated(test1),]
}
```

How can I efficiently configure test1, so that each row has one unique INT with all the corresponding categories pasted together in CAT (ie the for loop example)?

NB. Some integers will have no categories, and some will have more than one.

Thanks.

Comment: Do a data.table non-equi join. Study the package vignettes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dt1 <- dt2[dt1, on=.(INT_START<=INT, INT_END>=INT), allow.cartesian = T]

if (identical(dt1$INT_END, dt1$INT_START)){
  dt1 <- dt1[,c("INT_END", "CAT")]
  colnames(dt1) <- c("INT", "CAT")
  dt1 <- dt1[!duplicated(dt1),]
}

dt1 <- dcast(dt1, INT ~ CAT, value.var = "CAT")
dt1[is.na(dt1)] <- ""

dt1 <- data.table(INT = dt1[,1],
                  CAT = apply(dt1[,2:ncol(dt1)], 1, paste0, collapse = ""))
```

Comment: r u looking for `dt1[, CAT := dt2[dt1, on=.(INT_START<=INT, INT_END>=INT), allow.cartesian=TRUE, toString(na.omit(unique(x.CAT)))] ]`?